# Unable to scroll using mouse wheel with putty in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, putty

I am using cygwin and fvwm in windows 7 and using putty as a replacement for openssh, since it does not work for me anymore. The putty I am using came with cygwin and its version is 0.69. I startup putty from an xterm as follows:

```
$ putty -ssh <remote_host> -l <remote-user> 2>/dev/null &
```

On the xterms that I run inside cygwin there is no problem scrolling up using the wheel of the mouse. On putty clients that I run inside cygwin, for some reason, this does not work. I have to manually move the scroll on the putty to view output of prior commands.

I would like cygwin's putty to respond to mouse wheel the same way as the xterm responds.